# How To make a circle like this using canvas in Andriod

Tags: android, canvas

The problem is to make a circle which has more then one semi circles and having some text on that emi circle depends upon my text input array. how to make this in canvas.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use great [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). 
It supports circle graphs.

Comment: i want to make a circle image which has equally divided semi circles with name and color and set into an image view. chart library is good option but i want to make it in canvas.